# How to loop my try & except error code until the error is resolved (Negative Error)?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

So this is my code:

```
print('How many cats do you have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats)>=4:
        print('That is a lot of cats.')
    elif int(numCats)<0:
        print('You can\'t have negative cats, dumbo')
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats')
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number')
```

Currently, when I enter 'six', it outputs just the error message 'You did not enter a number' and the code ends there. I want the code to loop back to asking 'how many cats do I have' until I enter a non-error answer. Not sure how to do this. Would be great if anyone could offer this newbie some advice.

Mainly, I would like to know how to except a Negative Error, instead of writing an elif statement for it.

Comment: There is no "Negative Error", unless you throw one (which would also require a conditional)

Comment: What about this?

while True:
    print('How many cats do you have?')
    numCats = input()
    try:
        if int(numCats)>=4:
            print('That is a lot of cats.')
            break
        elif int(numCats)<0:
            print('You can\'t have negative cats, dumbo')
        
        else:
            print('That is not that many cats')
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not enter a number')

Comment: You can use the Tester-Doer Pattern, this basically means that you call a Function, which returns true if it was successfull and false otherwise. You can then call the method until it returns true

Comment: What about it? If you want to know how to manually throw exceptions, [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).